# Import module from child folder to parent

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, pythonpath

So I looked at various similar problems asked here but so far nothing worked for me.

I have the following file architecture:

```
\folder
    __init__.py
    supClass.py
    script1.py
    \sub
        __init__.py
        script2.py
```

So in script2.py I try to import supClass. If I understood well what I read on related subjects, I have to specify that `\folder` is part of the PYTHONPATH.

So following examples I read, I ended up with this piece of code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    from os import sys, path
    sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))

from test_package import supClass

    a = supClass()
    a.print_sup()
```

But I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Donnees/Programmes_Python/Developpement/Tests/test_package/sub/script.py", line 18, in <module>
    from test_package import supClass
ImportError: No module named test_package
```

I checked that \folder is now part of the PYTHONPATH by doing

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

in my console and it's ok. However, the `__package__` variable stays set to None.

The error I get seems to say that my `\folder` is not a module. I don't see why, maybe I am confusing things between "package" and "module".

Anyway, if anyone has an idea, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: The *parent* of `\folder` should be on `PYTHONPATH`.  Assuming `folder` == `test_package`, you can then do `from test_package import subClass` and `from test_package.sub import script2`.  Note that executing scripts from sub-folders is problematic (but easy if you write a `setup.py` file).  See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41201868/75103 for more info.

Comment: This works! Thanks! But can you explain why the parent of \folder should be on PYTHONPATH and not just \folder itself?

Comment: Because `folder` is your *package*, and to `import folder` Python needs to look in the directory *containing* `folder`.

Comment: Ok I get it now! Can you write an answer so that I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *parent* of `\folder` should be on `PYTHONPATH`. You can then do

```
from folder import subClass
```

and

```
from folder.sub import script2
```

The reason the *parent* of `folder` should be on `PYTHONPATH` (and not `folder` itself), is because `folder` is your package, and to `import folder` Python needs to look in the directory *containing* `folder`.

Note that executing scripts from sub-folders is problematic, but easy if you write a setup.py file. See my answer here stackoverflow.com/a/41201868/75103 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to import just supClass?

```
import supClass
```

Or try this:

```
sys.path.append("../")
import supClass
```

Comment: 'import supClass' does not work, and I get the 'No module named supClass'  error, which I get as supClass is nor in the same folder as script2, neither part of the PYTHONPATH. The second option leads to the same error. I think it just does the same as my script.

Comment: From wich directory do you execute the python file? Write how do you launch the program.

Comment: I launch the program directly from my IDE, so it should be from the '\sub' directory I guess.

Comment: ok, print(os.getcwd()) to check the directory. (import os #if you need)

Comment: so you have to try the second code i posted. Then to use it supClass.yourFunction()

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your hierarchy and this does the trick:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   from os import sys, path
   sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))

   from supClass import supClass
   a = supClass()
   a.print_sup()
```

Comment: Ok I tried that and indeed it works! But I don't get why I cannot import directlty `test_package`. I would like to import directly `test_package` so that I could use its `__init__.py`, which could contain the `from supClass import supClass statement`

Comment: __init__.py is a package file. Why do you want to call it?
Give a look at documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: No `__init__.py` is not the constructor of the supClass() class. supClass has its own constructor (which is a method called `__init__`) defined. But `__init__.py` is just the initialisation file required to define the folder as a python package.

Comment: Yes sorry I corrected myself, I was thinking about the init method. My fault.

Comment: I don't call the `__init__.py` explicitely. I just put inside the from `supClass import supClass` statement.

Comment: And is there a particular reason because you don't want to put the from supClass import supClass statement in script2.py?